# Application not running even after successful build

Tags: c#, winforms

Windows forms application is not running even after successful build. Whenever I run the application window doesn't shows up but in task manager .exe process is running. This is happens like for 3-4 times after which it will run successfully for 1 time.

Also when I close the application the process is running in task manager most of the time. So have to manually end the task.

Any help in this highly appreciated.

Comment: Unable to answer without seeing your code. This is highly unusual, though. Try to boil it down to a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe there's a sort of loop started before the UI is shown (if *endless*, the app would be killed after ~1 minute, though). Or a remote resource that doesn't answer and a procedure doesn't timeout (but there's usually a default Timeout when accessing remote resources, so the app should fail or, well, as before). Or a gazillion other possible causes. All determined by some piece of code, not by the platform itself. So, post that code.